# Strange Access behaviour regarding subqueries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this code in Access:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.course, p.date
FROM Student s, Participation p
WHERE s.id = d.student AND footballer = NO
```

When I run it, I get 10 rows. So I use it as a subquery the next time:

```
SELECT c.course, c.date
FROM Course c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT DISTINCT p.course, p.date
FROM Student s, Participation p
WHERE s.id = d.student AND footballer = NO)
```

and I get no results at all. So I remove the `NOT` in `NOT EXISTS` and I get all 15 rows that are in the `Course` table. So it seems to me that `course` and `date` from the subquery read from `Course` from the main query instead of from `Participation` from the subquery. But how is this possible since I have created different alias names and even the source tables are different (though they both contain columns with names `course` and `date`) and how do I solve the problem?

Comment: Dems answer should hopefully be what your looking for, if not for some reason; then is it possible to amend your question to simply what you would like to accomplish, and someone can then provide the SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sub-query is not related to the main query.  Try something like this?

```
SELECT c.course, c.date
  FROM Course c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT DISTINCT p.course, p.date
                     FROM Student s INNER JOIN Participation p ON s.id = d.student
                    WHERE footballer = NO
                      AND p.course = c.course
                      AND p.date   = c.date
                  )
```

This now takes every record in `Course` and runs the NOT EXISTS check for each row, filtering the `Participation` table by the `course` and `date` fields.

Your example just ran the sub query once.  It returned 10 records, and so the `NOT EXISTS` always failed.